# Join collections by id with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a object collection

```
var myData = new[]
{
    new {
        ID = "1285",
        COUNT = 45
    },
    new {
        ID = "1286",
        COUNT = 156
    },
    new {
        ID = "1287",
        COUNT = 965
    }
};
```

And my another collection comes from another data source like this:

```
var incomingData = new[]
{
    new {
        ID = "1285",
        LOCATION = "City-1"
    },
    new {
        ID = "1286",
        LOCATION = "City-2"
    },
    new {
        ID = "1287",
        LOCATION = "City-3"
    }
};
```

I want to change incoming data with COUNT property by Id.

```
var NewData = new[]
{
    new {
        ID = "1285",
        LOCATION = "City-1",
        COUNT = 45
    },
    new {
        ID = "1286",
        LOCATION = "City-2",
        COUNT = 156
    },
    new {
        ID = "1287",
        LOCATION = "City-3",
        COUNT = 965
    }
};
```

How can I do this with linq labda functions. I do not want to use foreach loop. (`myData` and `incomingData` collection lengths may be different)

Comment: If the collections are of differing lengths, what should happen to elements from one collection that don't appear in the other?

Comment: only matched items will be join

Comment: I see, thank you :) I think I was over-thinking this!

Answer (score 4):

Just use ordinary join statements like this:

```
var result= 
    (
        from data in myData
        join inData in incomingData
            on data.ID equals inData.ID
        select new
        {
            data.ID,
            inData.LOCATION,
            data.COUNT
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Easy, simple, readable

Comment: "Easy, simple, readable" - very!